# Pandas Styling not reading css id

Tags: css, pandas, itext7, pdfhtml

I'm generating the following html from pandas.

```html
<style  type="text/css" >
  #T_header_tablerow0_col3,#T_header_tablerow0_col4{
    background-color:  #F5ABAB;
  }
</style>
        
<table id="T_header_table" class="header-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >Threshold</th>        
      <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >Limit Amount</th>        
      <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >Utilization (Historical Cost)</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >Threshold Breach</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >Limit Breach</th>    
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >778.900000</td>
      <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >1</td>
      <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >2</td>
      <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0</td>
      <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I try to generate a pdf using itext from this html, the id based inline styling doesn't come into effect and I don't see the colors. Can anyone help me on this?

Here's my itext code

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(inputFile), new File(outputFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in pdfHTML. The exact problem is that it does not gracefully deal with IDs that start with an uppercase letter. So as a workaround you can change your HTML into:

```
<style  type="text/css" >
  #t_header_tablerow0_col3,#t_header_tablerow0_col4{
    background-color:  #F5ABAB;
  }
</style>

<table id="T_header_table" class="header-table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >Threshold</th>
    <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >Limit Amount</th>
    <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >Utilization (Historical Cost)</th>
    <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >Threshold Breach</th>
    <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >Limit Breach</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >778.900000</td>
    <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >1</td>
    <td id="T_header_tablerow0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >2</td>
    <td id="t_header_tablerow0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0</td>
    <td id="t_header_tablerow0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >0</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And it should produce correct result.
Meanwhile if you are considering to contribute to [pdfHTML](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml), you may wan to check out `CssSelectorParser` class and regular expression in `SELECTOR_PATTERN_STR` - the `(#[_a-z][\w-]*)` part is the one needs fixing.